# How to rotate in quaternions but for 2d version for arbitrary angle?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, rotations, quaternions

I am trying to understand the idea behind rotating in quaternions, but first I want to understand the math for 2d rotation. I saw some youtube videos, and I know that for 2D, a point in 2D can be represented like

$a + bi$ which maps to the $(x,y)$ coordinate $(a,b)$. Then lets say I want to rotate it 90 degrees. I would multiply $a + bi$ by $i$. So for example, if I had the point (3,3) so that's $3+3i$ then rotate it 90 degrees, I do

$(3+3i)i = 3i+3i^2 = 3i-3$ (since $i^2=-1$)

so that's
$-3+3i$ giving the point $(-3,3)$ which is a $90$ degree rotation of the original point $(3,3)$.

But what was not explained and what I don't get is, how to rotate by an arbitrary angle from 0 to 360? Like lets say I want to rotate by 20 or 45 degrees, what would I multiply the $a + bi$ with?

Can anyone explain?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the complex number $r=\cos \theta + i \sin \theta$, such that $|r|=1$.

For a complex number $z=x+iy$ we have:

$$
rz=(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)(x+iy)=x\cos \theta -y\sin \theta+i(x \sin \theta+ y \cos \theta)
$$

If we interpret $z$ as the vector ${\bf z}=(x,y)^T$ we can write this result as:
$$
{\bf z'}=
r\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta\\
\sin \theta& \cos \theta
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and we can see that the matrix represents a rotation of angle $\theta$, because the first column is the rotation of ${\bf i}=(1,0)$ and the second is the rotation of ${\bf j}=(0,1)$, that are the standard basis of the vectors in a plane.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you show an example please. So like if I had $(3,3)$ i.e. $3+3i$ and want to rotate it 20 degrees. Can you show what I would need to multiply it with?

Comment: So does it mean that first I need to convert $20$ to radians, so $q=radians(20)$. Then I do $(3+3i)(cos(q)+isin(q))$? And the result is the point where $(3,3)$ is rotated $20$ degrees?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. If you want you can also use $\cos 20°$ and $\sin 20°$, it is the same.